# what's the difference between is not null and <>' '

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Look my example, what's the difference between two codes?

```
Select name from customers where name is not null

Select name from customers where name <> ''
```

Comment: The first checks for null and the second for  a empty string

Comment: I test it and the second example checks for non-empty string and for NULL

Comment: Please share what you tested (sample data + actual results vs. expected results). My guess is that you are not interpreting your test correctly, but we can't say if you don't share what you did and with which data.

Comment: If you add a record where name is blank ie '' then run your test you will see that record is selected for the first statement but not for the second.

Comment: Add a check constraint that prevents zero length strings. NULL should be used instead.

Comment: The second statement definitely doesn't check for null.  It checks for empty string

Comment: If you want to find all rows where the name is not null and it is not an empty string the easiest way is to use > ''. This will exclude NULL because of how null comparisons work. Additionally there are no actual values for a any of the string types that can be less than ''. And above all else, it is sargable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do completely different things.

```
Select name from customers where name is not null
```

This one selects any customer who has a value in the name field. Those values can include '' as well as things like 'Sam', 'John Jones', 'pretty blonde girl'.

```
Select name from customers where name <> ''
```

This will select all names that are not null or blank In Sql Server at least. Other databases may handle this differently. The reason why it also excludes Null is that Null cannot be part of a comparison since it by definition means we don't have a clue what the value of this field is.

If you wanted to return both real names and null values and only exclude the empty strings. In SQl Server you would do:

```
Select name from customers where coalesce(name, 'Unknown') <>''
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of correct answers here but I think you are missing what NULL is. It's nothing so it's not comparable to anything. Here's some test for you

```
DECLARE @param CHAR(1)=NULL --you can replace @param with your column name in your queries

SELECT 1 WHERE @param = NULL   --you can't compare NULL to anything using = > < <> != or any other comparision operator
SELECT 1 WHERE @param = ''     --an empty value isn't the same as a NULL value so if a NULL is present it won't be returned
SELECT 1 where @param IS NULL  --this is how you have to check for null values

--If you want to check for both empty and nulls, you can force the empty string with COALESCE or ISNULL

SELECT 1 WHERE COALESCE(@param,'') = ''
SELECT 1 WHERE ISNULL(@param,'') = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

The key concept you are missing is that in SQL Server, **NULL does not mean no value, it means that the value is unknown**.  So consider your query with some silly sample data:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    ( id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , name VARCHAR(10) NULL );
INSERT INTO @t 
VALUES
    ('dog'),
    ('cat'),
    (''),
    (NULL);

SELECT *
FROM @t 
WHERE name <> '';
```

What you are asking the engine is to return the records where name is not an empty string.  On the evaluation of the fourth record, it is determining if NULL equals empty string or not.  NULL could be empty string, we don't know ... given that the value is unknown, the engine can't include that record because you are asking for only records where we know the name is definitely not empty string.

Consider another query against the same data:

```
WITH cteTemp AS
    (
    SELECT *
        ,   isEqualToEmptyString = CASE WHEN name = '' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END 
    FROM @t 
    )
SELECT *
FROM cteTemp
WHERE isEqualToEmptyString = 'false';
```

Now this is written to demonstrate a point and there are cleaner ways to do the same thing (such as the COALESCE in HLGEM's answer.)  But understand what is happening here: the query is first determining for sure what names are empty string (which excludes the NULL since its value is unknown) and then excluding those that are.  Thus, the NULL is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Null and empty string are two different things. A given field in a table can either have no value (null) or a value of an empty string (''). The results return by each query will be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Yes but when i use <> ' ' it ingnores empty strings and NULL values

Comment: In MySQL, DB2, SQL Server, Oracle, or something else?

Comment: @woz it's Oracle, I suppose

Comment: No i use sql 2008 server

Comment: I test  my second example and checks for non-empty string and for NULL values. But should i use both condition for avoiding sql injection?

Comment: You should use parameterization to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Is not null determines if the object/record being inspected is a true null value or not (no data).

`<> ''` means is not an empty string, so the record does contain data (that there is an empty string) and is not actually null.

So a query with is not null will return records with a value of string.empty, and a query with `<> ''` will return values that are neither null nor empty. To catch both empty strings and null values you should use `<> ''` in your SQL statements.

Comment: "*a query with <> '' will return values that are null*" - no it will not.