# Exclude null and other values in the where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
FROM 
    Table1 L
LEFT JOIN 
    Table2 M ON L.id = M.id
             AND ISNULL([Col1], '') NOT IN ('', '#N/A', 'NULL')
```

How do I write this logic in T-SQL where I want to exclude null, NA as well as the string NULL?

Comment: your query seems to be fine, what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: and your current condition is not working?

Comment: NULLS are included in the result set. Also I want to make sure this is the best way to write it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273967/whats-the-difference-between-is-not-null-and/39274273#39274273

Comment: Perhaps you don't want to have that as a join condition and instead have it as a where condition? e.g. change your `AND` to `WHERE`? (Note: This would make it equivalent to an inner join and not a left join, but it's hard to tell what you actually want without sample data)

Comment: as you are doing a left join if there is  no match in Table2 you will get a null

Comment: changing it to where instead of 'on' filters the results for NULLS . I was also hoping to get some advice on best practice to write this query.

Comment: It may be somewhat clearer to write it as `... and not ( [Col1] is NULL or [Col1] in ( 'N/A', 'NULL' ) );`. Tip: Always use aliases on all columns when applicable, e.g. `L.[Col1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities are to either use a `where` clause, which was also indicated by the title of this topic, or drop the `left` join.

```
SELECT ...
  FROM Table1 L
  JOIN Table2 M ON L.id = M.id
   AND ISNULL([Col1],'') NOT IN ('','#N/A','NULL')
```

```
SELECT ...
  FROM Table1 L
  JOIN Table2 M ON L.id = M.id
 WHERE ISNULL([Col1],'') NOT IN ('','#N/A','NULL')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      * 
FROM        Table1 L 
LEFT JOIN   Table2 M 
        ON     L.id = M.id 
           AND 
               M.id IS NOT NULL 
           AND 
               NOT(L.[Col1] IN ('#N/A', 'NULL')) 


SELECT      * 
FROM        (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE NOT(Table1.[Col1] IN ('#N/A', 'NULL'))) L
LEFT JOIN   Table2 M 
        ON      L.id = M.id 
            AND 
                M.id IS NOT NULL
```